# Does this sorting algorithm have a name? (Cross between select and merge)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I just thought of an interesting way to do a sort. I'm sure someone has thought of it before, but I've never seen it. It goes in two steps:

**1-** Iterate through the input list, pulling out sequences of items that are in order (not necessarily contiguous) into bins. Create one bin for each pass, until the list is empty.

**2-** Merge the sorted bins back together using a standard merge (repeated selection of lowest first element)

Here is a prototype I made in Python. The output below might be more illuminating.

```
items = len(unsorted)
sortedBins = []
# Pull out bins of sorted numbers, until the unsorted list is depleted:
while( len(unsorted) > 0 ):
  print "Unsorted list: " + `unsorted`
  highest = float("-inf")
  newBin = []

  i = 0
  while( i < len(unsorted) ):
    # Find items in unsorted list that are in order, pop them out:
    if( unsorted[i] >= highest ):
      highest = unsorted[i]
      newBin.append( unsorted.pop(i) )
    i=i+1

  sortedBins.append(newBin)
  print "bin[%i]: "%(len(sortedBins)-1) + `newBin`
  print

# Merge all of the sorted bins together:
sorted = []
while( len(sorted) < items ):
  lowBin = 0
  for j in range( 0, len(sortedBins) ):
    if( sortedBins[j][0] < sortedBins[lowBin][0] ):
      lowBin = j
  print "lowBin: %i: %i" % (lowBin, sortedBins[lowBin][0])
  sorted.append( sortedBins[lowBin].pop(0) )
  if( len(sortedBins[lowBin]) == 0 ):
    del sortedBins[lowBin]

print "sorted:" + `sorted`
```

It seems like the worst case (a completely reversed list) would take **n(n+1)** time if I'm not crazy (that is, n(n+1)/2 for each loop). The best case (an already sorted list) would take **2*n** time.

**EDIT:** It runs now, so stop complaining. Here is the output, which further demonstrates how it works:

```
Unsorted list: [1, 4, 3, 8, 3, 7, 9, 4, 8, 9, 3]
bin[0]: [1, 3, 3, 9, 9]

Unsorted list: [4, 8, 7, 4, 8, 3]
bin[1]: [4, 7, 8]

Unsorted list: [8, 4, 3]
bin[2]: [8]

Unsorted list: [4, 3]
bin[3]: [4]

Unsorted list: [3]
bin[4]: [3]

lowBin: 0: 1
lowBin: 0: 3
lowBin: 0: 3
lowBin: 4: 3
lowBin: 1: 4
lowBin: 3: 4
lowBin: 1: 7
lowBin: 1: 8
lowBin: 1: 8
lowBin: 0: 9
lowBin: 0: 9
sorted:[1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Using a combination of `for i in range( 0, len(unsorted) ):` and `unsorted.pop(i)` seems like it could be problematic... no?

Comment: I haven't studied the code thoroughly, but it might be a [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: You are right, it should probably be a `while` loop.

Comment: Have you actually tested this code?  It doesn't work for any `unsorted` lists I set.

Comment: @sberry2A I have now made the program compile, since apparently nobody was willing to think about it otherwise.

Comment: Okay, who's the wise guy who voted "Off Topic"? I would love it if you explained how this is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you're looking at **[strand sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand_sort)**, a modified [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort) that works by locating and removing "strands" of increasing values out of the original array, then merging all the strands back together.  It has best-case runtime O(n) if the input sequence is already sorted, and both average- and worst-case runtimes of O(n<sup>2</sup>), since the algorithm may have to make n passes over the array, each time pulling out just a single element.

So yes, this sorting algorithm has been discovered before, but you're better off just using a standard merge sort because the performance is much better.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a selection sort with an optimizing heuristic of starting at the last selected index instead of starting at the beginning, then making up the cost of that in your "merge" sequence.  You're right in that it's an O(n^2) algorithm.  It would do best with mostly-sorted (in descending order) lists, but I can't really imagine a situation where it would perform better on average than just a selection sort, so I doubt anyone's made/named exactly this algorithm before.

Comment: The way it's coded, this an O(n^2) time algorithm, but it doesn't have to be. OP could do a lot better with an improved [merge algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm). The first pass is an O(n) process. The first pass is O(n). The second pass can be improved to be O(n log m), where m is the number of bins after the first pass. The overall complexity is then O(n log m). In the worst case, m == n and in any case m = O(n). It remains, I think O(n) in space.

Comment: @Ted, I think you are on the right track, but it's not quite merge sort. The only thing it has in common with selection sort is that it iterates over the list multiple times. I believe this is a completely different algorithm. It splits (selects) the unsorted list into sorted lists and then merges them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there are some small bugs as others suggested, I am able to follow your logic. I would still call it merge sort, with a modified partitioning strategy.

Comment: You may have come closest to it. Thank you for considering my question and not being pedantic. As you say, it is very similar to merge sort, but that does not do any comparison-based selection, it is just merges all the way down. I think mine might be different enough to warrant a new name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bucket sort done backwards. Instead of placing buckets in order and then putting elements in them then sorting them, you are looking to find 'free' sorted buckets (except doing the comparison to determine if they are sorted costs the same as actually sorting a value so it isn't actually 'free' by any means on random data) then placing the sorted buckets in order.

On random data this algorithm will usually yield very few buckets of more than one item, in which case it denigrates to having a useless and expensive loop at the beginning followed by a standard sort in your second loop.